# Python not entering for loop in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame, and I really don't understand why the code isn't running this for loop. It definitely gets to the events() method, but it just isn't running the for loop inside. Does anyone know why?

```
def events(self):
        print('events') # This prints out
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print('for loop') # This doesn't print out
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -10
                    y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 10
                    y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -10
                    x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 10
                    x_change = 0
                self.x += x_change
                self.y += y_change
```

Comment: Maybe there is nothing to run? `pygame.event.get()` is None, empty, etc.

Comment: @Rabbid76, every frame update I run the events() method. Would this be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line

```
print('for loop') # This doesn't print out
```

does not get executed, it means that `pygame.event.get()` did not return an event.

A common beginner mistake is to call `pygame.event.get()` multiple times per frame, so make sure you only have one `pygame.event.get()` call in your game.

`pygame.event.get()` will clear the event queue once called, so if you don't handle all events that are returned you will miss them and another call will not return them again.

If you need to listen for events in other places than your main loop, just store the events in a variable. Here's an example that I wrote for another answer:

```
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), ((0, 0), (32, 16), (0, 32)))
        self.org_image = self.image.copy()
        self.angle = 0
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(200, 200))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.groups()[0].add(Projectile(self.rect.center, self.direction.normalize()))
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            self.angle += 3
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            self.angle -= 3

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.org_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, direction):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((8, 8))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color('orange'), (4, 4), 4)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.direction = direction
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)

    def update(self, events, dt):
        self.pos += self.direction * dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(self.rect):
            self.kill()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(Player())
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        sprites.update(events, dt)
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, `pygame.event.get()` is called only once. The result is stored in a variable `events` and then passed down to all sprites via the `update` method.

Comment: Oh ok. I run the pygame.event.get() method once in the main.py and once in this sprite.py file (this one). Thanks.

Comment: @I_keep_getting_downvoted I added an example of how I usually handle this situation.